# cdi produce method ignored

Tags: java, cdi

I am trying get properties from a application.properties file using cdi injection. My producer method is never called when my fields are used. So they are always null.What am I missing , doing wrong ?

Here is my producer class:

**propertyProducer**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.InjectionPoint;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

@ApplicationScoped
public class propertyProducer implements property{

    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(propertyProducer.class);
    private Properties properties;

    @Property
    @Produces
    public String produceString(final InjectionPoint ip) {
        return this.properties.getProperty(getKey(ip));
    }

    @Property
    @Produces
    public int produceInt(final InjectionPoint ip) {
        return Integer.valueOf(this.properties.getProperty(getKey(ip)));
    }

    @Property
    @Produces
    public boolean produceBoolean(final InjectionPoint ip) {
        return Boolean.valueOf(this.properties.getProperty(getKey(ip)));
    }

    private String getKey(final InjectionPoint ip) {

        return (ip.getAnnotated().isAnnotationPresent(Property.class) && 
                !ip.getAnnotated().getAnnotation(Property.class).value().isEmpty()) ?
                ip.getAnnotated().getAnnotation(Property.class).value():ip.getMember().getName();

    }
    @PostConstruct

    public void init() {    
        this.properties = new Properties();
        final InputStream stream = propertyProducer.class.getResourceAsStream("/application.properties");  
        if (stream == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("No properties!!!");
        }    
        try { 
            this.properties.load(stream);    
        } catch (final IOException e) { 
            throw new RuntimeException("Configuration could not be loaded!");   
        }   
    } 
}
```

my interface

```
import javax.enterprise.util.Nonbinding;
import javax.inject.Qualifier;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.FIELD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.PARAMETER;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

public interface property {
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER})
public @interface Property {
    @Nonbinding String value() default "";
    @Nonbinding boolean required() default true;
    }
}
```

and here is how I get injected properties trhough fields

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import com.kino.jax.property.Property;
import com.kino.jax.urlReader.URLReader;

@RequestScoped
public class caller implements callerInterface{

    @Inject
    @Property("appId")
    private String appId;

    @Inject
    @Property("devId")
    private String devId;

    @Inject
    @Property("certId")
    private String certId;

    @Inject
    @Property("ebayWsBaseUrl")
    private String ebayWsBaseUrl;

    @Inject
    @Property("ebayFindAndGetWsExtension")
    private String ebayFindAndGetWsExtension;

    @Inject
    @Property("ebayFindAndGetWsParam")
    private String ebayFindAndGetWsParam;


    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(caller.class);
    //private int maxResults;
    private final int REQUEST_DELAY=500;

    @Override
    public void run(String search) throws Exception {
        logger.info("inside caller class");
        String address = createAddress(search);
        logger.info("sending request to :: "+ address);
        String response = URLReader.read(address);
        logger.info("response :: "+ response);
        processResponse(response); 
        //Honor rate limits - wait between results
        Thread.sleep(REQUEST_DELAY);
    }
    private String createAddress(String search){
    //substitute token
    logger.info("preparing ws URL ");
    try{
        String address = ebayWsBaseUrl+ebayFindAndGetWsExtension+ebayFindAndGetWsParam;
        address.replace("[appName]", appId);
        address.replace("[keyWords]",search);

        return address;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        logger.fatal("could not get service property "+e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

and my homeManager where I get reference to caller class

```
//some code
public void callWS(String search){
    callerInterface call = new caller();
        try {
               call.run(search);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
       }
//some code
```

Comment: Why does `propertyProducer` implement `property`? Its not needed.  To give more info, can you an example of how you're injecting this field? and getting a reference to that class?

Comment: @JohnAment Tank you for your answer, there is no special reason propertyProducer implement property. Did it just to test if it has an effect or not.I edited my question so that you can see how my fileds are used.

Comment: What is the meaning of having an interface "property" (lowercase) around your qualifier interface "Property" (uppercase)? Seems unusual. I'd try to eliminate this and see what effect it has.

Comment: How do you get a reference to `caller`?

Comment: Looks like a CDI discovery problem. If your injected properties are null, it's pretty sure that your `Caller` class is not managed by CDI. Do you have beans.xml in `Caller` class archive? How do you call `Caller` class?

Comment: I see your point it might be the problem caller reference is not injected through cdi in my homeManager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're manually instantiating your class.  You need to keep a reference to `caller` in your beans.

If you're using CDI 1.1 and need to do static look up, you can use `CDI.current().select(callerInterface.class).get()` to get a reference.  Otherwise you would `@Inject callerInterface c`

Comment: thanks using to inject reference of caller

        `@Inject`
         `protected caller callerWS;`

Did the trick